# What kind of assault in this short video clip?

Tags: vocabulary, listening

I was watching this anime when I could not get what kind of assault (@ 13 sec.) the character had said in this short clip (24 sec.)?

I'm sorry the clip has been uploaded via a free account on Vimeo so we have to wait till it is ready for viewing. It might take half an hour from the time this post has been posted.

https://vimeo.com/103054830

Comment: I don't really think this sort of question is a good fit for ELL because I don't think it's likely to help any other users in the future, but I think many of us would be happy to help anyway--perhaps in [the ELL chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7227/english-language-learners)?  In this case, it says "a **frontal** assault".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for transcription, rather than a question about English.

Comment: How easy it sounds now! Thank you snailplane & @CocoPop.
I doubt I'd change anything but I'll throw what I have in mind anyway! Could not a specific listening question be as valid as a specific grammar question? After all, listening is part of English learning and the question here has a specific answer. As for the analogy, imagine a question about the meaning of a (word) in context posted by a non-proficient user; beginners would try to ponder about, advanced users would just pass. Same thing here I suppose!

Comment: You may want to check this [question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17673/would-you-please-help-me-complete-the-conversation). It might have slipped moderation but users who want to hone their listening skills might find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"...before launching a **frontal assault**."

See definition [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontal_assault).